# How do I view the insecure items on a secure page

Tags: internet-explorer, https, security

I have a web application which works perfectly fine on my own machines, perfectly fine on my customer's PCs but on their customers machines each page they visit they get a prompt for the Mixed Content coming up.

However it doesn't matter whether they answer yes or no to the question, they still get all of the functionality of the site.

We cannot ask them to disable the warning, since they would then consider our application not secure and not use it.

I've installed Httpwatch and none of the resources or urls being loaded are insecure.
The codebase for any flash objects is called using https:
I've checked for any removechild() function calls in the scripts and none of them are called on divs with a background image.
We have no calls to javascript:void anywhere in the codebase.

I'm at a loss as to what to check next.
Is there any way without being too intrusive, to find out what insecure objects the page is trying to load?
This has to be something that will work on IE7 or 8 as we are not allowed to install anything on their machines.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit untimely, but I was running into this issue today, and thought I'd chip in.  In the IE9 developer toolbar (F12), the console tab will give you a list of any items which cause a security warning on a secure page.

Answer (score 2):

Other than what Dean has suggested, Why not try installing firebug (Firefox) and see everything that the page requests?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the IFRAME, it could be as mentioned CSS.  The best way to tell if that's the case -- and I did so -- was to use the IE8 Developer Tools (F12) under Disable > CSS and see if the problem occurs.  If yes, not in CSS.  If no, in CSS.  (In my case, I had a hard-coded URL in background-image tag that used http://.  The fix was to make the image relative.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any links to #?

That is, I had an

```
<iframe src="#"/>
```

That caused exactly what you were describing.

Editing, any iframe without a src, or with a src that IE doesn't love, will cause this bug.  Also, there's potential that editing CSS to include images and using a relative URL may also cause this one, so dynamic drop down menus with a image of a down arrow on them might also cause the problem.

If you have access to the page, try removing chunks of it at a time, and see if the error still occurs to track down where on the page it might be happening.  iframes and then CSS would be my top two bets.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had a similar problem (mixed content warning on older IE browsers but no insecure content found by specifically designed tools).

Turns out it was caused by the http url specified at [*codebase*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#adef-codebase-OBJECT) attribute for the *object* element that was used to embed a Flash animation.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, it turned out to be CSS import statements pulling in sub-sheets which had absolute path elements in them.  In my case the sub-sheets were obsolete so I simply deleted the import statements from the main stylesheep.